# How to pass gmail message on express render parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-google-oauth

I used passport-google-oauth for authentication and `node-gmail-api` for fetching gmail ! So I want to display gmail message after authenticated so that I code like this in `routes.js`

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
      var gmail = new Gmail(req.user.google.token)
      , s = gmail.messages('label:inbox', {max: 10}),mm;

    s.on('data', function (d) {
       res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user, // get the user out of session and pass to template,
            mm: d.snippet,
            layout: 'header'
        });
    })
```

About code can get gmail messages but getting error like below and stopped the node server running

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
>       .....

If I write `res.render` outside of `s.on('data')` function , I can't pass mail snippet string in render . How can I render correctly with `node-gmail-api` message ?

Comment: `s.on()` is probably being triggered multiple times.  You can't call `res.render()` multiple times on the same response.  If you're trying to accumulate multiple results and then render them all, then accumulate them into an array and call `res.render()` on a different event when all the results are done.

Answer (score 0):

I got solved by as @Freddy suggestion on gitter.im,`s.on('data')` is piping / streaming data as it's fetched, and the first result I get is not necessarily the final / end result
Something like [Wait for callback of async function in last stream.on('data') event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464354/wait-for-callback-of-async-function-in-last-stream-ondata-event) should get on the right track
So, I need to wait for all the data from s.on( 'data' ) to finish, before I try and run res.render()

```
  var data

  stream.on('data', function (d) {
    data = d
  })

  stream.on('end', function () {
    t.equal(data.id, '147dae72a4bab6b4')
    t.equal(data.historyId, '6435511')
    t.equal(data.messages.length, 1)
    t.equal(data.messages[0].snippet, 'This is a test email.')
    t.equal(stream.resultSizeEstimate, 1)
    t.end()
  })
})
```

In above case, the data is collected and stored in the data variable before I can use it in the end stream.`stream.on( 'end'` is where I should put **res.render** like below ...

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
      var gmail = new Gmail(req.user.google.token)
      , s = gmail.messages('label:inbox', {max: 10}),data;

    s.on('data', function (d) {
       data = d;
    })
    s.on('end', function () {
      res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user, // get the user out of session and pass to template,
            mm: data.snippet,
            layout: 'header'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes ! With your help .